# How to write devapp property to deploy.properties file

Tags: powershell, biztalk

We have a biztalk solution with BTDF implemented. We are using Urban code for automation.We are trying to set one property from `prebuild.ps1` file to `deploy.properties` file. How can I do that? I tried below code added in `prebuild.ps1` file but no luck.

`$DeployPropertiesSrc` → path to `deploy.propeties` file
`$versionToUse` → version

```
echo “deployApps=@(Projectname -$versionToUse)” >> $DeployPropertiesSrc
```

Also tried to copy one property from using PowerShell script to property file:

```
echo “deployApps=@(Projectname)” >> $DeployPropertiesSrc
```

Comment: Define "no luck". What result did you expect? What result did you actually get?

Comment: As a side note: you may want to avoid typographic quotes in scripts. Even though they work most of the time they occasionally do cause problems.

Answer (score 0):

#### Example 1

Assuming the `$DeployPropertiesSrc` and `$versionToUse` variables are defined in the script file, you can add the following to that script:

```
$DeployPropertiesSrc = "<FolderPath>\deploy.properties"
$versionToUse = "10.0.2"
"deployApps=@(Projectname -$versionToUse)" | Add-Content $DeployPropertiesSrc
```

Here are the contents of the **deploy.properties** file after running the code:

```
Get-Content $DeployPropertiesSrc
deployApps=@(Projectname -10.0.2)
```

#### Example 2

If variable values are in your current scope and you don't want them stored in the script file, then you can update your script file to use parameters passed to it. Keep in mind that for simplicity I'm using undeclared parameters here.

Contents of the **prebuild.ps1**:

```
"deployApps=@(Projectname -$($args[0]))" | Add-Content $args[1]
```

Then you can call the above script with arguments like so:

```
& .\prebuild.ps1 "10.8" ".\deploy.properties"
```

Or:

```
$versionToUse = "7.10.3"
$DeployPropertiesSrc = "some_path\deploy.properties"
& .\prebuild.ps1 $versionToUse $DeployPropertiesSrc
```

- If deciding on the parameter route, I would personally choose to use
  named parameters. If the named parameters are not set to mandatory,
  you can have some control of whether that code block executes and even assign default values to the parameters. If this part of the script is made into a function, you gain another level of control. Using
  undeclared parameters without having any argument checks, could
  result in unwanted errors. Sometimes you may want to call the script with no arguments and it will have errors if you only add the code block in my example 2 alone.